# Get request attribute with Spring webflux and WebTestClient

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I'm not able to bind an attribute that I'm setting from a `WebTestClient` into a `RestController` when using Spring WebFlux.

I tried the two ways I could think of.

First using the `@RequestAttribute` annotation and I got:

> Failed to handle request [GET /attributes/annotation]: Response status 400 with reason "Missing request attribute 'attribute' of type String"

Then I tried with the ServerWebExchange and was `null`.

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/attributes")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/annotation")
    public Mono<String> getUsingAnnotation(@RequestAttribute("attribute") String attribute) {
        return Mono.just(attribute);
    }

    @GetMapping("/exchange")
    public Mono<String> getUsingExchange(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Mono.just(exchange.getRequiredAttribute("attribute"));
    }
}
```

And this is my failing test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    WebTestClient webClient;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        webClient = WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context)
                .configureClient()
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAttributeUsingAnnotation() {
        webClient.get()
                .uri("/attributes/annotation")
                .attribute("attribute", "value")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAttributeUsingExchange() {
        webClient.get()
                .uri("/attributes/exchange")
                .attribute("attribute", "value")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk();
    }

}
```

In my real application I have a SecurityContextRepository that sets some attributes from a (decoded) header value and I'd like to get those attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Both on the server and client side, request attributes should be seen as Map-like data structures that can be used to transfer information within the client/server (for filters, codecs, etc).

That information is not sent over the network.

If you want to send that information from the client to the server, you should take a look at request params or the request body itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware that this attribute is being set on server side by decoding a header (JWT) and I can successfully get the attribute using the `ServerWebExchange` when I send the header. However I'd like to make my test simpler by setting the attribute directly as I was able to do with `MockMvc` before webflux, just like this: `mvc.perform(get(...).requestAttr("foo", "bar"))`. And that used to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same issue with a test which previously used MockMvc and then had to be converted to use WebClient. Like @jcfandino I was expecting the `.attribute()` methods on the WebClient to work similar to MockMvc's `requestAttribute()`.

I haven't found out how `.attribute()` is meant to be used but I've bypassed the entire problem by adding a custom test filter. I'm not sure if this approach is *correct* but since this question has been unanswered the approach below may be of help for people running into the same issue.

```java
@WebFluxTest(controllers = SomeController.class)
@ComponentScan({ "com.path1", "com.path2" })
class SomeControllerTest {

    // define a test filter emulating the server's filter (assuming there is one)
    private class AttributeFilter implements WebFilter {

        String attributeValue;
        
        public AttributeFilter(String filterAttributeValue) {
            attributeValue = filterAttributeValue;
        }
        
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
            // add the desired attributes 
            exchange.getAttributes().put(SomeController.ATTR_NAME, attributeValue);   
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        }
    }
   
    // mock the service the controller is dependend on
    @MockBean
    AppService appService; 

    // define the test where the controller handles a get() operation 
    @Test
    void testMethod() {
        
        // mock the app service
        when(appService.executeService(anyString(), anyString())).thenAnswer(input -> {
            // ... return some dummy appData
        });

        var testClient= WebTestClient.bindToController(new SomeController(appService))                
                .webFilter(new SomeControllerTest.AttributeFilter("someValue"))
                .build();

        try {            
            var response = testClient
                .get()               
                .uri("someroute")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody(AppData.class);                             
                
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("exception caught in testMethod", e);
        }
    }
}
```